# Should I update posts that have been "unduplicated"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Twice my questions have been voted duplicate and twice I've voted to reopen and been successful in that endeavor.  No complaint there, all actions were legitimate IMHO.

In both cases, I added additional text to the posts to justify why they were not duplicate.  However, now that they have been reopened, those edits no longer seem relevant.  *Should I again edit, removing "no dup" justification text or just leave the posts as they are*.  Questions are:

- [Can a pilot rated in one category solo in another category without a current flight review?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42587/can-a-pilot-rated-in-one-category-solo-in-another-category-without-a-current-fli)
- [Is it better to shut down the engine(s) or leave it (them) running when a gear up landing is imminent?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/40867/is-it-better-to-shut-down-the-engines-or-leave-it-them-running-when-a-gear-u)

Comment: I've updated both mentioned questions to reflect suggestions in the answers.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's definitely good that you updated your questions to add more explanation about why they aren't dupes and therefore get them re-opened. That's exactly how the system is supposed to work!

My only 'concern' is an entirely subjective one: although your wording is perfectly clear I personally don't like it. It's a little jarring to read that "this question is marked duplicate" when in fact it isn't any more. My view is that a question should be fully understandable and coherent on its own, without requiring someone to read or even think about previous edits or changes.

Personally, instead of this (from your first question)...

> **In response to this being marked duplicate:**
>
> I was aware that a biennial flight review is valid for any airplane
>   category [...]

...I'd have written something like this:

> I've already seen this related question but I don't believe it's a
>   duplicate because it doesn't cover the case where a biennial flight review [...]

That provides exactly the same explanation, but it still reads smoothly if the question is later re-opened, and it doesn't have any 'meta-references' to edits or status changes.

Comment: Point taken and I will try to improve my wording in the future and perhaps on those question as well if the consensus is that I shouldn't just remove the section altogether.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I again edit, removing "no dup" justification text or just leave the posts as they are

You should definitely leave the posts as they are when reopened.

If you remove the explanation and the reference to the other question, nothing prevents a future user to pass by and vote it to close a duplicate again, as they would not have any idea that the discussion has been settled in the meanwhile.

For this reason I strongly agree with Pondlife's point: you should write the rebuttal to stand on its own, without references to the current status of your question. For example you can look at [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23810/1467), that was closed as duplicate but has been since reopened.